# Need Tifffile.size to output width and height

Tags: python, size, tiff

Due to my raster size, I am forced to use the `tifffile` library to read my image in. I am trying to obtain the width and height parameters of the raster, but am unsure how to do so with `tifffile`. I have found with `PIL` that `your_image.size` will output `(numbers, numbers`) which is what I need. `tifffile` - `your_image.size` will only output `numbers`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tifffile uses numpy conventions. Try `your_image.shape`. Also check the [examples](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile#examples).

Comment: Perfect! Could you please answer the question and I will accept it?